# How do you know whether to trade one of the rook pairs in an endgame?

Tags: endgame, rook-endgame, trading

I've been reading *Endgame Strategy*. I've seen, in a lot of the games, trading one of the rook pairs can help. There is a chapter in the book called the 'Problem with Exchanging.' I don't know how to determine when trading one of the rooks is beneficial for me.

Comment: I often trade with my rook pair for any piece as long as the opponent king had none left and when i have a passed pawn or has better pawn formation.

Comment: Are you referencing a double rook endgame?

Comment: @overtheboard Yes. I'm referring to any endgame that has two rooks. I sometimes see one of the two rooks get traded for the other rook. One side gains an advantage from trading one of the rooks. I was wondering when does trading one rook create an advantage in such an endgame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One question to ask is "am I behind or ahead?"  If I have some winning edge, it's best to simplify.  If I'm behind, it's better to complicate the position.

After that, the question has both tactical and positional elements.  If my rook is less active then my opponent's, it's better to exchange.  If my rook is more active, then it's better to keep it.

Comment: Unless the only way to keep it is to make it less active.